# Inconsistent behaviour while debugging and executing without debugging

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am writing a small windows service using .net framework 3.5 and its exibiting a wierd behaviour. The code gets stuck on

```
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=abc;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz;Unicode=True"))
        {
```

. . .

however when I debug it by attaching debugger to the service its working fine. Absoulutly clueless on this.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple threads trying to initiate DB connection?

Comment: How many oracle connections does your service have open at this point?

Comment: Well that should not be the case.. as currently there is only one thread executing. however in future that might be the case

Comment: Don't know, have never done so with Oracle (have with other DBs but there isn't much consistency in this).

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, have you put a breakpoint on that line and are you running the exe compiled in debug mode? i remeber a colleague , many years ago, being drived crazy because he execute an exe built with option debug instead of release which stopped on breakpoint. As i said this just a guess, maybe its not valid for lastes .net and vs version

Comment: I have deployed the debug release

Comment: and have you left a breakpoint somewhere? try to deploy a release version

Comment: yep there are lots of break point left. I also tried deploying a release version and still no luck

Comment: weird, are you sure that's the point it get stuck ? are you logging something (exceptions, actual operation being executed) , there's nothing inside windows event viewer?

Comment: yep i introduced textfile logging to get to this point. I have a log entry just before and after the statement

Comment: after the statement ? then it must stop inside the using, not at connection creation, try post the code inside the using